Writing data to a virtual serial port: Doesn't work when going from Host to Guest
VM Setup
My host computer uses MacOS. My guest VM uses Ubuntu Server 20.04. I am using VirtualBox as my VM tool.
I used the following socat command to creat two virtual serial ports:
socat -d -d -T -1  pty,raw,link=/tmp/ttyV0 pty,raw,link=/tmp/ttyV1

These are my VM's serial port settings
VirtualBox Guest OS Serial Port settings
Here's the problem
I have two python scripts,

Script1: writes an integer to serial port every second that increments
Script2: is constantly reading from the serial port

When Script1 is running on the Guest machine and Script2 is running on the host machine, I can see in the terminal output the incrementing integers being sent. It will first print everything in the buffer till it catches up and then prints the integers in real time as they are being sent by Script1.
When Script1 is running on the host machine and Script2 is running on the guest machine, I only see whatever Script1 wrote to the serial port up to the point Script2 was run. Once it reads everything in the buffer, it doesn't keep printing integers in the console in real time as they are being sent by Script1. If I kill the Script2 and run it again, it then prints what was sent in that interval and pauses. It doesn't print in real time.
I also ran Script1 and Script2 on the host machine itself and everything works smoothly. This makes me think it's an issue with VirtualBox or with how the serial port behaves.
Any idea why it can't read in real time from the guest machine?
